# Tkinter - Images is not display

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am  new on Tkinter. I was trying to display two images on my canvas but I couldn't. I tried to achieve this by creating two different files. One will contain all logic behind and the other one will handle the gui. Here is my code so far:

file1.py

```
from file2 import *

import tkinter as tk

import random

# global variables
w = 'initial'

class start_gui(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)
        # create canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, width=800, height=800, background="green")
        self.canvas.pack()

        c = Display(self.canvas)
        c.current_play(w)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      # create main window
      root = tk.Tk()
      root.geometry("800x800")
      start_gui(root)
      root.mainloop()
```

file2.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

class Display:

    def __init__(self, canv):
        self.canvas = canv


    def current_play(self, option):
        if (option == 'initial'):
            self.initial_display()
        elif (option == 'n' or option == 's'):
            self.ns_display()

    def initial_display(self):
        # display cat image
        self.im = Image.open("cat.gif")
        self.photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.demo = self.canvas.create_image(400, 400, image=self.photo_image, anchor='center')

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")

        self.temp_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="cat.gif")
        self.demo2 = self. canvas.create_image(600, 600, image =  self.temp_image, anchor='center')
```

The problem here is that the two image items I created do not show up on the canvas but only the rectangle. Can someone help me with this?

PS: I am using python v 3.4

Comment: .gif image is in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution: We can make `Display` inherit from class `tk.Canvas`

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

import random

# global variables
w = 'initial'

class Display(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self,  parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)


    def current_play(self, option):
        if option == 'initial':
            self.initial_display()
        elif option == 'n' or option == 's':
            self.ns_display()

    def initial_display(self):
        # display cat image
        self.im = Image.open("cat.gif")
        self.photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.demo = self.create_image(400, 400, image=self.photo_image, anchor='center')
        self.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")

        self.temp_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="cat.gif")
        self.demo2 = self.create_image(600, 600, image = self.temp_image, anchor='center')


class start_gui(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)
        # create canvas
        self.canvas = Display(parent, width=800, height=800, background="green")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.current_play(w)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x800")
    start_gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of garbage collection. Your `Display` object is stored in a local variable inside `start_gui.__init__`. Once `start_gui` is constructed, this object is thrown away. The image is an attribute of that object, so it gets garbage-collected. When an image object gets garbage-collected, tkinter is unable to display it.

The simple solution is to keep a permanent reference to `Display`:

```
self.display = Display(canvas)
self.display.current_play(w)
```